# Why does lapply() convert my R data frame to list?

Tags: r

I was modifying a data frame in R with `lapply()` and observed that my data frame was converted to a list object when I didn't use brackets to assign it.

For example, the following returns a list

```
junk <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3,
                   col2 = c("a,b,c"),
                   col3 = c(T,T,F))

junk <- lapply(junk, function(x) {
    if (is.numeric(x)) return(x*2)
    else return(x)})

str(junk)
```

where as the following returns a data frame.

```
junk <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3,
                   col2 = c("a,b,c"),
                   col3 = c(T,T,F))

junk[] <- lapply(junk, function(x) {
    if (is.numeric(x)) return(x*2)
    else return(x)})

str(junk)
```

I'd like to know why `[]` preserves the data frame structure, and what `[]` is doing in this case. I understand why the first code chunk converts `junk` to a list, but don't understand why the second chunk preserves structure, though I couldn't think of a clear title to describe the question/situation. Thanks.

Comment: That behavior exists for convenience. If you want to know the details, you could look inside the function `\`[<-.data.frame\``. (It should boil down to what Li Zheyuan said, though.)

Comment: Thanks both of you appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is natural for `lapply` to return a list, because it is not always guaranteed that function `FUN` returns processing results of the same size.

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,2), b = c(1,1,1))
lapply(dat, unique)
```

The second does not preserve structure by modifying the original data frame in place. It does this

```
tmp <- lapply(...); junk[] <- tmp; rm(tmp)
```